# For which integers x, y is $2^x + 3^y$ a square of a rational number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, contest-math

For which integers x, y is $2^x + 3^y$ a square of a rational number?

(Of course $(x,y)=(0,1),(3,0)$ work)

Comment: There is at least one more solution: $(x,y)=(4,2)$.

Comment: It can be shown that all solutions with $x,y \geq 1$ must satisfy that both $x$ and $y$ are even.

Answer (score 2):

Case 1:

Let's try the case $x,y\geq 1$ first. Let $2^x+3^y=n^2$ (where $n>0$). We notice that $3\not|n$, therefore $n^2\equiv 1(\mod\,3)$. Now consider the equation $2^x+3^y=n^2$ $(mod\,3)$, we get that $(-1)^x\equiv n^2\equiv 1(\mod\,3)$. Hence $2|x$. Let $x=2u$. Thus, $4^u+3^y=n^2$. Now move the $4^u$ to the other side to get a difference of squares:
$$3^y=n^2-4^u=(n-2^u)(n+2^u)$$
3 can't divide both of $(n-2^u),(n+2^u)$. Hence either $n+2^u=1$ (clearly not the case) or $n-2^u=1$.Thus, $n+2^u=3^y$. Hence:
$$1=n-2^u=3^y-2^{u+1}$$
Now we know from Catalan's Conjecture that ..... (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_conjecture) and we're done with the first case.

I am almost sure the other cases can be handled similarly but I feel lazy (I might be wrong though).

Edit: Ivan Loh noted that Catalan's Conjecture may be avoided. The argument that would replace Catalan's conjecture is in the comments

Comment: "Now move the 4y to the other side to get a difference of squares:" <- You have a typo in there ;o

Comment: @Magtheridon96 Tthanks ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I also got to the point that $x$ and $y$ must be even and therefore $3^y = (n - 2^u)(n + 2^u)$ (even with the same notation $u$...) but then somehow failed to notice that $3$ cannot divide both. Time for bed, but not before I (+1) you :)

Comment: @TMM Thanks. I find it strange that contest problems require knowledge of Catalan's Conjecture. Thus I think there is another solution.

Comment: Catalan's conjecture is definitely not needed here. Just continue with the same approach to show that $y$ is even, then factorise difference of two squares again.

Comment: @Ivan Loh how would you show that y is even ?

Comment: Take $\pmod{4}$.

Comment: @IvanLoh OK Clever.

Comment: @IvanLoh But then what? Let $y=2v$, then $1=3^{2v}-2^{u+1}$ hence $2^{u+1}=(3^v-1)(3^v+1)$...

Comment: @Ivan Loh Ah now you get smaller (u,v) such that $2^u=3^v-1$

Comment: $3^v-1$ and $3^v+1$ are both even powers of $2$, and they cannot be both divisible by $4$...

Comment: @IvanLoh OK! you are leaving the case $3^v-1=2$ as it can be checked by hand, arent you ?

Comment: Well, I was just providing the general approach, since comments are supposed to be brief. Trivial cases are best addressed in the answer itself.

Comment: @IvanLoh I see. I was just making sure. Nice Alternative

Answer (score 2):

There are also negative integer solutions as well.  Consider $(-4,-2)$ where the expression then becomes $\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{9} = \frac{9}{144}+\frac{16}{144} = \frac{25}{144}$ which is the square of $\frac{5}{12}$.

Comment: Yes In general if $2^x+3^y$ is a square and $x,y$ are even , then $2^{-x}+3^{-y}$ is a square as well. To see this just divide by $2^x3^y$